# OpenAM is hung and high CPU utilization by Java

Tags: java, performance, apache, tomcat7, openam

I recently started working in a project which uses OpenAM for single sign on top of tomcat 7 and server running on Apache 2.4.12.

**Installed Java version details:**

- java version "1.7.0_65"
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment  (rhel-2.5.1.2.el6_5-x86_64 u65-b17)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
- OpenAM 11.0.0 (2013-November-08 10:40)

Most of the time 95% of CPU utilization is by java. I can't find the reason for this high CPU utilization.

We had an issue today with OpenAM, OpenAM Tomcat processes seems to have hung in two servers out of 8 and not listening to the port 8180. After restart, the service is up and running fine with ports listening.

However, I could see below error in openAM logs, I tried to find the root cause but unfortunately I can't, could anyone please help?

### Server 1:

```
Jul 28, 2015 8:33:36 AM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextDestroyed
INFO: WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed
Jul 28, 2015 8:33:43 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/sso] appears to have started a thread named [com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jul 28, 2015 8:33:43 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/sso] appears to have started a thread named [Monitor Provider State Updater] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jul 28, 2015 8:33:43 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/sso] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@4ee2edc3]) and a value of type [org.glassfish.grizzly.ThreadCache.ObjectCache] (value [org.glassfish.grizzly.ThreadCache$ObjectCache@1467c5ab]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 28, 2015 8:33:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8180"]
Jul 28, 2015 8:33:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
```

### Server 2:

```
 Jul 28, 2015 8:34:50 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/sso] appears to have started a thread named [com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jul 28, 2015 8:34:50 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/sso] appears to have started a thread named [Monitor Provider State Updater] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jul 28, 2015 8:33:43 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/sso] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@4ee2edc3]) and a value of type [org.glassfish.grizzly.ThreadCache.ObjectCache] (value [org.glassfish.grizzly.ThreadCache$ObjectCache@1467c5ab]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 28, 2015 8:33:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8180"]
Jul 28, 2015 8:33:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8180"]
Jul 28, 2015 8:33:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8109"]
Jul 28, 2015 8:33:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8109"]
Jul 28, 2015 8:33:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Jul 28, 2015 8:33:50 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
```

Other WARNING in Server 2:

```
Jul 28, 2015 8:35:13 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl newResourceClass
WARNING: A sub-resource method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.forgerock.openam.forgerockrest.authn.AuthenticationRestService.getMethodNotSupported(), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
Jul 28, 2015 8:35:13 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl newResourceClass
WARNING: A sub-resource method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.forgerock.openam.forgerockrest.authn.AuthenticationRestService.authenticate(javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
Jul 28, 2015 8:35:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat7/openam/webapps/manager
```

Comment: Are you able to replicate the issue?

Comment: @doveyg  yes, memory leak is happening most of the time, since it is happening in production we are doing forceful tomcat restart and releases memory. issue can reproduce in test environment as well.

Comment: You may want to collect some useful information on the problem before asking for help: http://blogs.forgerock.org/petermajor/2014/02/troubleshooting-101/

Comment: @PeterMajor sorry, i started working in OpenAM just 3 weeks ago and i am not aware of many OpenAM related things. i will follow the instructions from the above site and update

Comment: If you can reproduce it, what are you doing to cause it?

Comment: if load is high, issue can be reproduced

Comment: So then, in theory, you should be able to replicate the issue on one of the other six servers. What is the difference between the other servers and the ones that are experiencing the problem. Assuming its not a hardware issue and the code is the same, it must be a config issue. Cant you copy over the config from one of the good servers to the bad servers?

Comment: in fact all the servers is having the same configuration, i will double check and correct the configurations if any mismatches were found.